# How to change RangeSlider color from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a range slider with the below code dynamically from JS

```
$.get(PATH_DYNAMIC_PAGE + 'tempCreateScheduleNew.html', function (data) {
    $('#content').html('<div data-role="rangeslider" id="temperatureRangeSlider2"></div>');
    $('[data-role="rangeslider"]').append('<label for="range-2a">Time:</label>');
    $('[data-role="rangeslider"]').append('<input name="range-2a" id="range-2a" min="0" max="1440" step="15" type="range">');
    $('[data-role="rangeslider"]').append('<label for="range-2b"></label>');
    $('[data-role="rangeslider"]').append('<input name="range-2b" id="range-2b" min="0" max="1440" value="1440" step="15" type="range">');
    $('#content').append('<div id="temperatureTimeValuesContainer2">');
    $('#temperatureTimeValuesContainer2').append('<input type="text" id="temperatureTimeValues2"/>');

    $('#content').trigger('create');
    $('#content').append(data);
}
```

Now I would like to change the color of the selected portion in the slider with some other color dynamically from JS. I have tried with the below code but does not seem to be working.

```
$('#temperatureRangeSlider2').on('slidestop',
    function () {   
        //var color = getColor();
        $('.ui-widget-header').css('background','green');
        $('#temperatureRangeSlider2').rangeslider('refresh');
    });
```

Could you please help me get this working?

Comment: are you using jquery slider?

Comment: please share the plugin link and a demo if possible

Comment: @Cerlin Boss - we are using jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css & jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$('#temperatureRangeSlider2').on('slidestop',function () {   
    //var color = getColor();
    $('.ui-slider-track .ui-slider-bg.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active').css('background-color','red');
    $('#temperatureRangeSlider2').rangeslider('refresh');
});
```

NOTE: If you have more than one slider in a page then this code will affect all the sliders.

Comment: Great thanks Cerlin, it works for me with some minor change. It was working only for the first time so I change it as below to get this working -

if ($('.ui-slider-track .ui-slider-bg.ui-btn-active').length > 0) {
     $('.ui-slider-track .ui-slider-bg.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active').css('background-color',color);
    }
    else {
     $('.ui-slider-track .ui-slider-bg').css('background-color',color);
    }

Comment: also a small tip `if ($('.ui-slider-track .ui-slider-bg.ui-btn-active').length > 0)` can be written as `if ($('.ui-slider-track .ui-slider-bg.ui-btn-active').length)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery slider, you can do it with css if you want to only change the color of selected portion.....this should work

```
div.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header {
    background: red;
}
```

with javascript also, you should be able to apply the same css on the fly.

```
$('div.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header').css('background','green');
```

Comment: can you create the fiddle please?